# Setting up a Git project with a development remote and a read-only provider repository in subfolder

Tags: git, drupal

Have been following the tutorial in the following link to set up Drupal project with Git:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/803746

I ended having the following:

- Local working copy
- My own remote repository with two branches: dev and my-project
- Link to Drupal git repo (the readonly repo)

Now I want to move all the Drupal files/code into the subfolder `www` to be able to add more non-browsable files outside the www folder

I used `git mv` to move everything in www and committed and pushed the changes to my own repo. And everything is fine, but now I lost the connection to the Drupal repo.

How can I add an extra remote specifying that its root should be www rather than the same root folder as the already remote in use?

I read about sub-modules and sub-trees but all seamed to suggest that the sub-tree will overwrite changes not merge them, and probably will not allow pushing changes to the main remote.

Comment: Questions: you had Drupal as a remote? Did you make changes to the Drupal code?

Comment: In general no, except: 1- installed modules and themes are added in the same folder as drupal source 2- some patches are applied to core of drupal 3- everything in this folder is committed to origin (my own repo).

Comment: What do you mean by "link to Drupal git repo"? Is this the connection you lost?